# Clearing the tmp folder with Swift onAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've found that `AsyncImage`s tend to take up a lot of space in the tmp folder with a bunch of `CFNetworkDownload` files. Is there a simple way to clear the tmp file on load in Swift (using SwiftUI)?

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            // Content
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Clear tmp folder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really an issue you need to worry about? Are you going to download multiple gigabytes of images? These files should get cleaned up by iOS automatically if space runs low since they're cache files.

Comment: @DarkDust Honestly, yes. I'm finding multiple gigabytes of images (the app is a store) after using the app for extended periods of time